# How can I use \underrightarrow command with iopart.cls class?

Tags: amsmath

I would like to use `\underrightarrow` command which is included in `amsmath.sty` package. But, the publisher forces to use `iopart.cls` class, which is incompatible with `amsmath.sty`.

Any alternative command to use with `iopart.cls`?

Comment: Do you have the possibility to use Xe- or LuaLaTeX? If so, you may use the package `unicode-math` and its command `$\underrightarrow{x}$`. Does not look really nice but something at least.

Answer (score 3):

For very mysterious reasons, the class `iopart` doesn't want its users to load `amsmath`, which sounds very strange. In my opinion, the class should *require* the package and not trying to reinvent the wheel.

Anyway, here's code drawn from `amsmath.sty` (with just a slight change), that defines the construction you need.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\underarrow@[3]{%
  \vtop{\ialign{##\crcr$\m@th\hfil#2#3\hfil$\crcr
  \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern.12\baselineskip}#1#2\crcr}}}
\providecommand{\underrightarrow}{%
  \mathpalette{\underarrow@\rightarrowfill@}}
\providecommand\rightarrowfill@{\arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\rightarrow}
\providecommand\arrowfill@[4]{%
  $\m@th\thickmuskip0mu\medmuskip\thickmuskip\thinmuskip\thickmuskip
   \relax#4#1\mkern-7mu%
   \cleaders\hbox{$#4\mkern-2mu#2\mkern-2mu$}\hfill
   \mkern-7mu#3$%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\underrightarrow{abc}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the following MWE, I just disable the colliding definitions of `iopart`. There might be other problems... I do not know that documentclass. Maybe you should read a bit in the `iopart` documentation in order to gain knowledge about their anti-`amsmath`-decision.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{iopart}
\expandafter\let\csname equation*\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname endequation*\endcsname\relax 
\usepackage{mathtools} % which loads amsmath as well.

\begin{document}
Here is an underrightarrow for you: $\underrightarrow{x}$
\end{document}
```

[image]